# Phonegap build + Cordova 3.5 - Preferences not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Using Cordova 3.5 and phonegap build I have added preferences to my config.xml as described in the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File_global_preferences)

Example:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

My problem is, when i open my app (testing iPhone 5S, ios 7) the settings don't do anything, ie the orientation does not lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be using the Build documentation, here:

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences

In this case they are the same as the regular preferences.

Have you tried taking the capital letter off Fullscreen and Orientation?

Comment: Thanks @ Subjective Effect, lowecase did the job. PG documentation is really bad, i refused to believe it was that easy :/

Comment: No problem. I've been using PGB long enough to know how simply frustrating it can be. But its a great great service so stick with it!